# React native touch Id, get the count of number of fingerprint touches , touched by user

Tags: reactjs, authentication, modal-dialog, native, fingerprint

I am using react native touch Id and after multiple wrong attempts for fingerprint, the modal should be closed automatically without clicking cancel button. Is that possible? This is client requirement

I tried using react native touch Id library but because it uses system modal, I'm not able to close it automatically without clicking on cancel